# URL encoded characters on clicking link and page not found

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

I am getting the following error using Django 2.1:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/user-accounts/%5Eregister/
Using the URLconf defined in my_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
user-accounts/ ^register/$ [name='register']
user-accounts/ ^login/$ [name='login']
user-accounts/ ^logout/$ [name='logout']
bank-accounts/
The current path, user-accounts/^register/, didn't match any of these.
```

When I click a link in the header set in my base.html, I get the strange url `http://localhost:8000/user-accounts/%5Eregister/` in browser. The links in base.html are:

```
<li class="dropdown-header"><a href="{% url 'user-accounts:register' %}">Register</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-header"><a href="{% url 'user-accounts:login' %}">Login</a></li>
```

The user accounts app urls.py:

```
from django.urls        import path
from django.contrib     import admin
from .                  import views

app_name = 'user-accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    path(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
]
```

The project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from user_accounts.views import register

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', register),
    path(r'user-accounts/', include('user_accounts.urls')),
    path(r'bank-accounts/', include('bank_accounts.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's new (>=2.0) [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path) function does not work with regular expressions. That's why the `^` character is literally prepended to the URL.

If you want to keep using regular expressions, use the [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path) function.